# LatLong to XYZ data viz

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude

I'm somewhat of a noob when it comes to coordinate systems and projections.

I am woking on wind visualization and I am coming across two issues that I am not sure why they are happening.

For context, it is a particle sysstem that uses the global winds as the force vector. All the math of the particle system is done on the Lat and Long and the last step is that I convert it to [x y z] coordinates.

I'm a bit lost as to why I am getting these issues.

1. The Equator is drawing a line ( i suspect it is  on the negative latitudes):
   [image]
2. The poles appear to be pulling in data:
   [image]

**Edit** I think the errors might have to do with the convertion from LatLong to xyz. Here is what the system looks like when I map it to on xy only: [image]

Here is  the code I  use for the conversion:

```
// calculate x,y,z from spherical coordinates lat,lon 
Particle latLongToXYZ(Particle p) {
    float phi = p.currLatLong.x * PI / 180.0;
    float theta = p.currLatLong.y * PI / 180.0;
    
    float sinPhi, cosPhi, sinTheta, cosTheta;
    sinPhi = sin(phi);
    cosPhi = cos(phi);
    sinTheta = sin(theta);
    cosTheta = cos(theta);
    p.worldPos = vec3(cosPhi * sinTheta, sinPhi, cosPhi * cosTheta);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Is your globe really 3 dimensions?

Comment: The [Tour] also emphasizes the One question per Question policy. Asking two questions is likely to get your Question closed for lacking *focus*.